# Can't align "pointer targets signedness"

Tags: c, gps, uart, hal, signedness

I've been struggling with this issue for a while where this code

```
uint8_t *PMTK = "$PSIMIPR,W,115200*1C";
```

gives me the error

> pointer targets in initialization differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]

Changing it to only `char *` or `unsigned char *` does not make a difference, and `const char *` causes the program to complain further down where PMTK is supposed to be used, in the following code:

```
if (HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, PMTK, 32, 2000) != HAL_TIMEOUT)
          {
              HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_7);
              HAL_Delay(500);
              HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_7);
          }
          else
          { ....
```

The program is supposed to establish uart communication from STM32F0xx to a GPS receiver (SIM33ELA), using HAL driver.

Comment: For problems with compiler error messages, always include your compiler name and version in your question.

Comment: @unwind The 2000 is a timeout counter, not the length of the string. `HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_UART_Transmit
(UART_HandleTypeDef * huart, uint8_t * pData, uint16_t Size,
uint32_t Timeout)`
@user694733 Sorry, compiler is Atollic TrueSUDIO, version 9.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's a really *annoying* corner of the STM32 Cube libs. Someone should give them a big clue that random read-only buffers are best expressed as `const void *` in C ... mumble.

So, to fix it: It's convenient to use a string literal since the data is textual. So, make it so and then cast in the call, instead:

```
const char PMTK[] = "$PSIMIPR,W,115200*1C";

if (HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t *) PMTK, strlen(PMTK), 2000) != HAL_TIMEOUT)
```

Note use of `strlen()` to get the proper length, hardcoding literal values is never the right choice and was broken here (the string is not 32 characters long). We could use `sizeof` (it's an array, after all) too but that's bit more error-prone since you must subtract 1 for the terminator. I'm pretty sure compilers will optimize this `strlen()` call out, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

c Strings are treated by the compiler as char[]. If you add a cast to (uint8_t *) before the String the warning is quieted.

```
uint8_t *PMTK = (uint8_t *)"$PSIMIPR,W,115200*1C";
```